# add rows with strings between a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices that i have concatenated vertically. However, i want to insert 2 or more rows in between them with a string in those rows.. how do i go about doing that.? 
 Basically this is what i have;

```
 A =    0.7363    0.8217    0.7904    0.5144    0.5341
        0.3947    0.4299    0.9493    0.8843    0.0900
        0.6834    0.8878    0.3276    0.5880    0.1117
        0.7040    0.3912    0.6713    0.1548    0.1363
        0.4423    0.7691    0.4386    0.1999    0.6787
        0.0196    0.3968    0.8335    0.4070    0.4952
        0.3309    0.8085    0.7689    0.7487    0.1897
        0.4243    0.7551    0.1673    0.8256    0.4950
        0.2703    0.3774    0.8620    0.7900    0.1476
        0.1971    0.2160    0.9899    0.3185    0.0550
```

But i want it to be;

```
 A =    0.7363    0.8217    0.7904    0.5144    0.5341
            0.3947    0.4299    0.9493    0.8843    0.0900
            0.6834    0.8878    0.3276    0.5880    0.1117
            0.7040    0.3912    0.6713    0.1548    0.1363
            0.4423    0.7691    0.4386    0.1999    0.6787

            MESH       PART
            0.0196    0.3968    0.8335    0.4070    0.4952
            0.3309    0.8085    0.7689    0.7487    0.1897
            0.4243    0.7551    0.1673    0.8256    0.4950
            0.2703    0.3774    0.8620    0.7900    0.1476
            0.1971    0.2160    0.9899    0.3185    0.0550
```

Comment: you cant. In MATLAB, a matrix can only be of 1 type

Comment: I think the question would be more readily dealt with if we knew why you wanted to do this.  What's the purpose and intended use of the intra-matrix column headers?

Comment: If your problem only concerns with displaying the matrix like this, first divide the **A** matrix into two part (**A1**,**A2**) and  add `disp('MESH PART')` between **A1** and **A2**.

Comment: i am using that matrix as a sample rather than messing with my real data that i am going to use. Actually, i have two matrices, one with X Y Z coordinates and the other with connections of the coordinates.. and i have to save the files in a DAT file together in order to import them as a mesh into CATIA. but i dont think CATIA distinguishes between the coordinates and the connetions when importing, that is why i want to insert spaces and strings between them @TroyHaskin

Answer (score 0):

Assuming CATIA can read the output correctly, you could simply set `A` as a `cell` variable, which can contain both numbers and strings of characters. This is achieved by using the brackets { }, as opposed to [ ] for numeric matrices. In your particular case, I would write:

```
A =    {0.7363    0.8217    0.7904    0.5144    0.5341; ...
        0.3947    0.4299    0.9493    0.8843    0.0900; ...
        0.6834    0.8878    0.3276    0.5880    0.1117; ...
        0.7040    0.3912    0.6713    0.1548    0.1363; ...
        0.4423    0.7691    0.4386    0.1999    0.6787; ...
        'MESH'    'PART'    '-'       '-'       '-'   ; ...
        0.0196    0.3968    0.8335    0.4070    0.4952; ...
        0.3309    0.8085    0.7689    0.7487    0.1897; ...
        0.4243    0.7551    0.1673    0.8256    0.4950; ...
        0.2703    0.3774    0.8620    0.7900    0.1476; ...
        0.1971    0.2160    0.9899    0.3185    0.0550};
```

The '-'s next to MESH and PART are for consistency with the matrix (in this case, cell) size. I hope this works for you.

Comment: That would have been really , but for me to use that dont i have to write the whole data by myself? the thing is that the one shown above is just a sample data, the real data is over a thousand numbers.. so is there a way to do it without typing all the data?

Comment: Sure, probably some kind of loop would work, but it depends on the data you're using. If you're willing to share how your data is structured/stored, and where you need to add the strings, I could guide you as how to do it.

Comment: You wouldn't have to use a loop, you could just use [`num2cell`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), so `A = [num2cell(A(1:5,:)); {'MESH', 'PART', '', '', ''}; num2cell(A(1:end,:))]`